# Regex after specific word and special characters

Tags: regex

I have a string like that:

```
{"success":true,"result":[{"firstname":"Mark","lastname":"White","birthday":"1976-11-12","id":"12x1288"}]}
```

Can someone help me with a regex to find the matching value after a specific field?

For example after lastname": i know that the value will be between the next double quotes. It could be two words, or it could be empty, but always between double quotes.

Thanks!

Comment: Stop right there.  Your input is _JSON_, so you should probably be using a JSON parser to read it, _not_ regex.

Comment: You are right thanks! I managed to do it with a JSON parser, much easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using a JSON parser, such as [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). But, to answer your specific question, here is some code that should help you:

```
    String s = "{\"success\":true,\"result\":[{\"firstname\":\"Mark\",\"lastname\":\"White\",\"birthday\":\"1976-11-12\",\"id\":\"12x1288\"}]}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("lastname\":\"([^\"]*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Prints:

> White

It looks complicated, but that's just because I'm having to escape all the double quote characters. I match up to the quote character surrounding the field value, then in a capturing group, match zero or more characters that are *not* quotes. These represent the value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to do it by using the JSON Parser, you are very nice!